# Permission Denied Nginx CSS File Django-Gunicorn Local VM

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-server

can helpme?

My application in django does not load the css when I use gunicorn + nginx below I have permission error:

```
2023/07/05 16:29:51 [error] 18862#18862: *1 open() "/home/victor/helpme/tickets/static/css/style.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.0.106, server: 192.168.0.113, request: "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.113", referrer: "http://192.168.0.113/ticket_list/"
```

**My socket file:**

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn helpme socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn_helpme.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
~
~
~

**My Service File:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn_helpme.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=victor
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/victor/helpme
ExecStart=/home/victor/helpme/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn_helpme.sock \
          ticket_system.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Nginx:**

```
ps auxf | grep nginx
victor     18883  0.0  0.0   6476  2308 pts/0    S+   16:34   0:00  |           \_ grep --color=auto nginx
root       18860  0.0  0.0  55196  1716 ?        Ss   16:29   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   18861  0.0  0.2  55864  5596 ?        S    16:29   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
www-data   18862  0.0  0.2  55864  5596 ?        S    16:29   0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

**Sites-enabled**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name 192.168.0.113;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/victor/helpme/tickets;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/victor/helpme/tickets/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_helpme.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    access_log off;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/temp.otaviomiranda.com.br-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/vm-error.log;
}
```

**Folder Project Permissions**

```
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 4,0K jul  5 16:26 helpme
```

I asked pro chat gpt he raised questions about selinux, but he is inactive! still the CSS presents error to read the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me a lot as well. this is the snippet you can use:

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /home/victor/helpme/tickets #for nginx user
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/victor/helpme/tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

Your static/media location definitions are miss configured right now. You've given full access to allow anyone to browse your tickets directory because you stop the path at the tickets folder instead of going one deeper to the static/media files. Even if you fix the permission issue you should still have issues without fixing those paths.